# Github error message: git-it: command not recognized

Tags: git, shell, github

Just installed GitHub for Windows and have done the configuration part by typing in

```
$ git config --global user.name "<Your Name>"
$ git config --global user.email "<youremail@example.com>"
```

with my name and email entered in the proper place.

The problem is when I try to verify it using the command
`git-it verify`
I am getting an error saying `git-it: command not recognized`.

Could any of you tell me how to fix this??

EDIT: I think I should also add that when I give the command
git --version
it shows the version as git version 2.7.1.windows.1
Doesnt this mean that git is already installed??

Comment: install it before using as @Raghavan said http://jlord.us/git-it/challenges/get_git.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install git-it before you can use it as a command . git-it does not get installed when you install Github for windows . Use this to install git-it

```
npm install -g git-it
```

and try.

Comment: okay, i tried this and it says 
bash: npm: command not found

I think I should also add that when I give the command
git --version
it shows the version as git version 2.7.1.windows.1
Doesnt this mean that git is already installed??

Comment: You have install npm in your machine before you can install git-it using npm .

Comment: well, I didnt know that. 
I'd like to add that all of the above works in the browser, but it doesnt work on my machine. so do I need to install npm as well as node js on my machine??

Comment: Yes , we need to have npm to install git-it . Pls refer to docs of git-it :https://github.com/jlord/git-it#install-git-it

Comment: Aha! got it. let me do that and get back to you

Comment: Yes, it works now Raghavan.
There's just one problem though.
I am following the tutorial on http://jlord.us/git-it/challenges/commit_to_it.html
and have done whatever it said on my machine and it worked
but now I dont see the change reflected in the browser
I have added the readme.txt file in the hello-world directory
but I dont see the file in the browser.
why is that?
what am I doing wrong??
even the previous challenges such as git-it and repository I had to do it on both my machine and the browser.
seems like I am missing something.

Comment: This seems to another question altogether . Pls post it as separate question . Also Accept the answer for this question if you think it has help you solve the problem as it will help others seeking the same question .